# AngularJS store form data in variable issue

Tags: angularjs, forms

I'm using an NG-submit button to try and tie the click event of the submission data to an angular variable and running into an issue.

Angular code:

```
formApp.controller('formController', function ($scope) {

// we will store all of our form data in this object
// function to process the form
$scope.processForm = function () {
    var fn = $scope.firstname;
    alert('your reccommendation has been submitted!' + fn);


};
```

Where NG-submit is located in html

```
<form id="signup-form" ng-submit="processForm()">
                <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
                <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
            </form>
```

Where the first name data is filled in at:

```
 <strong>First Name:</strong>
<input name="FirstName" size='16' ng-model="firstname"  />
<br />
<br />
```

Now before you say the NG-submit is not located near my form, the form view is tied to that initial one. The alert works just fine when you press submit but the variable returns **undefined**. Any assistance would help!

Comment: What do you mean by *"the variable returns undefined"*? You aren't returning anything, anywhere

Comment: Sorry returned was a bad word to use I guess, in the $scope.process form function I am trying to get the first name form data using the ng-model to be stored in that variable "fn" and then alert it out after submit is pressed, it shows undefined on the alert instead of the name inputed.

Comment: Ah, assuming you're using another controller in your `ui-view` there, any data defined in that controller's scope won't propagate up to the parent. This looks like a bad way to structure a form

Comment: Our routes to different pages are nested in the view which should be controlled by the formController.

Comment: Might not work but you could try `ng-model="$parent.firstname"`. Still seems like a bad idea to me

Comment: "parent" meaning the name of the parent controller?

Comment: No, literally `$parent` meaning the current scope's parent scope ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$parent

Comment: You a sick boss, it worked!  Do you know of a better way to accomplish this? Or do you think that if it works it's all right?

Comment: I would not have a form that wasn't aware of what was inside it. I still cannot fathom why you would build your app this way

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just a silly student trying to learn ;). Thanks for the information though!